# Map projection with System.Drawing.Graphics

Tags: c#, geospatial, projection, system.drawing, map-projections

I have a set of geo coordinates as latitude/longitude pairs that I wish to project onto a 2D surface. Some of the coordinates are connected by lines forming a shape/outline/polygon.

I understand how to project individual points using one of the many available map projections like Mercator and then drawing them with [Graphics.DrawArc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawarc?view=net-5.0) but how do I go about projecting the connecting lines between them? I can't just project the two defining coordinates of a line and draw it [Graphics.DrawLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawline?view=net-5.0#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawLine_System_Drawing_Pen_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_) because every single point on that line has to be projected as well, right? I don't know much about these things, so I hope you understand what I mean.

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do using just the methods provided by the [System.Drawing.Graphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics?view=net-5.0) class? Can I do this with a projection matrix? If anyone could explain a bit how I would go about doing this, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your are only drawing lines it is probably easiest just to subdivide the lines into short segments, project each segment point and draw straight lines between them. This might not be the most performant or exact way to do it. But it should be fairly easy to implement.

For example:

```
    public static void DrawSubdivided(this Graphics g, Pen pen, Vector2 p1, Vector2 p2, float subdivisionLength)
    {
        var d = p2 - p1;
        var length = d.Length();
        // Add check for zero-length lines
        var dn = d / length;

        var points = new List<Vector2>();
        for (float l = 0; l < length; l += subdivisionLength)
        {
            points.Add( p1 + dn * l);
        }
        points.Add(p2);

        // apply transformation to the points

        g.DrawLines(pen, points.Select(p => new PointF(p.X, p.Y)).ToArray());
    }
```

This uses System.Numerics.Vector2 since it has reasonable arithmetic operations defined, in contrast to PointF.